# Vim regex equivalent in vs code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In Vim I can use `:g/^\s*T\y A` to copy all lines starting with `T` in a file to `register a`, then paste it to wherever I need it from said register.
How can I, or what is the equivalent regex to do the same in Visual Studio Code?
Be mindful that I am NOT fluent with regex and two days new to VS Code. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can copy to multiple registers like that in VSCode unless someone has an extension to do it.  Otherwise, one at a time you can:

Put `^\s*T.*$` in the search field

<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> will select all occurences of those matches

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy to clipboard

Then paste to where you want it.

Comment: It's a couple more buttons of work but does exactly what I need it to do. Thanks